# IONIC Cordova walk-through not working on actual device

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an IONIC 1 ios application and I am trying to implement cordova walkthrough in it. Its working fine on simulator and iphone 5 devices but its not showing on iphone 6 plus & higher devices.

I am using this library: https://github.com/souly1/ng-walkthrough

Here is the css which I am using:

```
.walkthrough-hole {
position: absolute;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1997px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1997px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1997px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
border-radius:1px
-webkit-appearance: none;
 }
```

Comment: Just connect your device to safari remote device debug, inspect your component and check which CSS rule does not work.

Comment: @sjahan Yes, I know how to debug but its happening in device of our users and I don't have access of those devices and I don't have 6+ device with me. I am heavily dependent on simulator and iphone 5 device but issue is coming in 6+ devices.

Comment: That is strange... I've just tested on an iPhone 6s. It works fine from what I can see: I get a massive black shadow (slightly transparent): `moz-box-shadow` and `webkit-box-shadow` are properly overriden by `box-shadow`. What is the result when it does not work?

Comment: There is no black shadow in 6 plus what users are saying they are just seeing text at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

After checking on some more devices, I came to conclusion that this was device specific issue. Its working fine on most of the devices including 6 plus.

It wasn't a code issue.